# Is this how we write radian

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $\theta$ = Arc Length / radius of circle.

Then it is theta = metre/metre .Then , we say theta has the unit radians.

So why is m/m radian?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193684/why-are-angles-dimensionless-and-quantities-such-as-length-not

Comment: Radians are dimensionless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Only angles have a symbol. Not like refractive index which have no unit".

I see.

> In optics, the refractive index (also known as refraction index or
> index of refraction) of a material is a dimensionless number that
> describes how fast light travels through the material. It is defined
> as
>
> $ n=\frac {c}{v},\ $ where $c$ is the
> speed of light in vacuum and $v$ is the phase velocity of light in the
> medium.

We *could* create a unit for refractive index, like $refrix$. If so, we would say, "the refractive index of light in Perspex is $1.52\ refrix$."

But we don't *need* to. We can just say, "the refractive index of light in Perspex is $1.52$". And it's unambiguous what we mean here, because there's no *other* commonly-utilised English term for "ratio of the speed of light in a vacuum and the phase velocity of light through the medium".

However, unfortunately we have two *different* commonly-utilised ratios that describe an angle between two straight lines that meet at a point (First, extend the lines so that they have the same length. Then draw the circle). One is:

$$\frac{\text{arc length}}{\text{radius}}.$$

The other is $$\frac{\text{arc length}}{\text{radius}} \times \frac{180}{\pi}.$$

We must distinguish between these two ratios because they are different and they are both commonly-used, therefore we give them different names. If we didn't give different names, then it wouldn't be clear which one we are referring to/talking about.

Answer (score 1):

> SI system has seven base units plus two supplementary units: radian and steradian. The latter two don't add to the dimensions, and are dimensionless.

Okay, angle is dimensionless quantity, so why should we assign an dimensionless unit to it? Simply because, if we do not, then we won't be able to distinguish between simple numbers and angles.

Angles are *different* from normal numbers, and hence need a distinction. This can be done by some symbol or so. This symbol is itself designated as an unit.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Only angles have a symbol. Not like refractive index which have no unit

Comment: Refractive index is a number, a mere number.